# Wordpress login bug. Need an emergency solution

Tags: htaccess

I need emergency solution. I can’t login in to my WordPress site. After giving username and password it redirects to `site/wp-login.php` and shows a blank page. It does not take to the dashboard. I have deleted all previous data from the site and installed WordPress several times. Even I have installed several versions of WordPress. But I can’t login to my admin panel in anyway.

Important to mention that I have deleted `.htaccess` file from the root directory of my site. I am new in WordPress. Actually I can’t understand where the problem is. Is this happening because of missing `.htaccess` file? Someone told me to talk with the hosting provider to solve this.

Comment: Perhaps you are getting [white screen of death](http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors#The_White_Screen_of_Death)? Try to enable [debug mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: the problem is associated with hosting provider

Comment: if it is an hosting problem then it is off-topic and best resolved with the help of your hosting support

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not related to a "missing" .htaccess file.  WordPress will create an .htaccess file if needed (for permalinks) and re-create a deleted file if needed.

If you have deleted all previous data as you state and installed WordPress several times, you likely have a very messy DB and/or file situation going on.

Why not simply create a new DB, clear all the files out and start from scratch?  5 minutes or less and you have a fresh clean WP site ready to work with.